throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set'); ^ Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
I am trying to send an attachment to an API endpoint UploadFxPLink, but I keep getting the following error:
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:645:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (D:\NIDC\BL1\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (D:\NIDC\BL1\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (D:\NIDC\BL1\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
    at ServerResponse.send (D:\NIDC\BL1\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:158:21)
    at Request._callback (D:\NIDC\BL1\ors.js:2848:11)
    at self.callback (D:\NIDC\BL1\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Request.onRequestError (D:\NIDC\BL1\node_modules\request\request.js:877:8) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}

I understand this error usually means that headers (like status code or content-type) are being set after the response has already been sent, but I’ve checked my code and made sure I’m returning a response for every path.
Here’s the relevant code:
app.post('/UploadFxP', function (req, res) {
  var trackngNo = req.session.TrackingNo;
  var attachmentId = req.body.attachmentId;
  var trackNo = req.body.trackNo;
  var userId = req.session.userID;
  var token = req.session.token;
  var atachment = req.body.atachment;
  var attachment = atachment.replace("data:application/pdf;base64,", "");

  console.log('trackingNo: ', trackngNo)
  if (req.session.userID) {
    request({
      url: UploadFxPLink,
      method: 'POST',
      json: {
        trackNo: trackNo,
        trackngNo: trackngNo,
        userId: userId,
        attachmentId: attachmentId,
        atachment: attachment,
        token: token
      },
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    }, function (error, response, body) {
      if (error) {
        console.log("Failed to UploadFxP " + error);
        return res.send({ "failed": "failed" });  // added return here
      }

      return res.send({ "success": "success" });  // added return here
    });
  } else {
    res.redirect('/');
  }
});


Try to replace
  if (error) {
    console.log("Failed to UploadFxP " + error);
    return res.send({ "failed": "failed" });  // added return here
  }

  return res.send({ "success": "success" });  // added return here

with
  if (error) {
    console.log("Failed to UploadFxP " + error);
    res.send({ "failed": "failed" });  // added return here
  }
  else {res.send({ "success": "success" });  // added return here}
  

If it not helped you try to replace
headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
      }

with
res.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);

If and this not helped you - share more code
